# append columns in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been able to append a new row of data from an imported and live updating postgres import on google sheets. My requirement is to get the data to append in a new column, next to the one previous.

```
   // function to save data
  function saveData() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var count = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A3').getValue();
    var date = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!B3').getValue();

    sheet.insertColumnAfter(sheet.getMaxColumns());
    sheet.getRange(1,sheet.getLastColumn(),2).setValues([count,date]);
  }
```

Im getting the error of not being able to turn an object into an array - any help?

Comment: try `sheet.getRange(1,sheet.getLastColumn()+1,2,1).setValues([[count],[date]]);
`

Comment: Thats nearly worked completely! its taking the two values that are side by side and updating them one on top of the other in the next column - so 90% there !! I'll have a play and see if i can jig it about!

Comment: **one on top of the other** = a column. thats what you mentioned in question. if the row position is not right, change the first **1** to starting row.

Comment: Thank you ! sorted it now! absolute hero

Answer (score 1):

```
function append() {

  var tabLists = "append"; //my sheet is named as "append"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);

  sheet.clear()


  var date = new Date('October 11, 2018 09:15:00')

  var sr = 4
  var sft = 1 
  var sc = 1
  var nr = 1
  var nc = 1


  for(var i=0; i<5;i++){  //I'm appendind 5 columns for now.

    sheet.getRange(sr,sc,nr,nc)//(start row, start column, number of rows, number of 
columns)
    .setValues([[
      date
    ]]);
    sc = sc + 1
  }
}
```